# What does this Salesforce forumula (DATETIMEVALUE) mean?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am looking at this formula:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(({!$Record.StartDateTime__c})-4/24)
```

What does -4/24 means? Minus 0.1666 (4/24=0.1666)?  What does this formula do? If this is minus 4 hours due to Day Light Saving, how can I have a generic formula that covers both Eastern Standard Time and Day Light Saving Time, without manually changing 4 to 5 when it is back to Eastern Standard Time? Hard-coded value doesn't make sense in production.

Another related question: where can I find Salesforce documentation about use of "4/24". Googled a lot and wasn't able to find relevant documentation or similar examples about use of "4/24".